# How do I troubleshoot DBUS/MPRIS (media keys)? Not working after unity install on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, dbus

Volume control (up/down) worked fine. It behaves fine.
Media keys (next/previous) isn't working.

It seems like the actual keyboard shortcuts are registered, the media application don't receive anything. If I assign a keyboard shortcut as shown below using DBUS to control e.g. spotify, it works fine:

**dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.spotify /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Next**

Setting "media keys" through the unity gui however, does not work.